# GCC 5 or newer version

Tags: gcc, debian, gcc-warning, gcc5, gcc4.6

I need to install an application on a device with the following features. but it must be GCC 5 or newer. Is it possible to upgrade this? Thank you.

Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy)

G++ (Debian 4.6.3-14) 4.6.3

I'm beginner and I didn't understand some of the resources I looked at, so I wanted to ask here. Thank you.